# How to install .cab file on wince 6.0? Also which application is needed to install .cab file on wince 6.0?

Tags: windows-ce

How to install .cab file on wince 6.0? Also which application is needed to install .cab file on wince 6.0?

Please Reply
Thanks

Abhineet Agarwal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the ability to install CAB files on WinCE 6 add the **CAB File Installer/Uninstaller** (SYSGEN_WCELOAD) catalog item to your image. The application that installs it is [wceload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504595.aspx).

#### How to add the catalog item

You go to the catalog, check the item you want.

[image]

Then do a Sysgen (<kbd>Build</kbd>→<kbd>Advanced Build Commands</kbd>→<kbd>Sysgen</kbd>). After the Sysgen phase is complete you should be able to install the cab file

Comment: If you are looking to learn Windows CE without a course, a nice place is http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/Default.aspx

Comment: @Shaihi does this mean that one has to rebuild the OS package and reinstall that new os/'platform package' in order to add this functionality?

Comment: As far as I remember and know - yes - but I have not handled this for a long time